# how to check the user id of the user logged into the network using ipad app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, networking

i have a wifi network that is authenticated. when the ipad is connected in that network i want my ipad app to bypass the login and use those credentials to login to my app. is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to find the particular user that was used to connect to the wifi through iOS.  You might be able to do this if you have a server on your local network that is responsible for authenticating the username/password given to connect to the local wifi netowrk and then associate that with the address of the device.  Then you could have a service that the iOS device could query and get the username from it.

So, you'd have

1. iOS device connects to network with
   username/password
2. wifi router authenticates user and
   logs username + MAC address
3. you app sends request to server on
   network with the iOS device's mac
   address
4. server looks up mac address and
   finds the username associated with
   it (from the second step)
5. server returns username to iOS
   device app and you continue your app with that user

Comment: thanks i have got some idea now. But with the reachability code is it possible to detect reachability for authenticated networks???

Comment: I think I commented on this in your other thread of the question.  You would have to set the reachability to look for a server that is only on your authenticated network.  For example, if you have a server named "internalserver" then use that for the reachability instead of something out on the internet.

Comment: where would i give my authentication details then??

Comment: That would be down to the server on your authenticated network.  That's something that is dependent on your network and the rest of the system architecture and could be one of many possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the user's credentials in your app using NSUserDefaults after a first successful login.

But .. There is no API in iOS that will allow you to connect to a particular WiFi network, that is under your user's control.

Comment: i dont want to connect to the network from the app. i just want to check if the ipad is connected to that particular network is it possible to check through which user credentials the network is authenticated and connected. i mean the username alone.